# Overfitting, overtraining, or incorrect architecture

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a 6*32 arrays of let say technological data, which looks like "rays", connecting local maximums of some or all of six rows, and going at some angle upside down:

```
1:     100 (102) 97  98 127 120 121
2:      88  87  (91) 90  88  88  88
3:     101 100  101 100 101 100 100
4:      99  97   97  98 (99) 98  97
5: ...
6: ...
```

My basic idea was to use CNN networks because currently operators detect these patterns visually, and problem does not seem too difficult in comparance to text or photo objects recognitions. I use Keras and following architecture give the best results. Unfortunately, only at training.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=( 6, 32, 1)),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='tanh', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='tanh', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='tanh', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='tanh', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=4, activation='tanh', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=4, activation='tanh', padding="same"),

    keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Dense(8096, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.6),
    keras.layers.Dense(8096, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.6),

    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    ])
```

Compile:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), 
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training:

```
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=200, batch_size=128)
```

At training it gets loss ~0.1667 accuracy ~0.9480
At test accuracy is only 61%.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have an over-fitting problem, so you need to **increase regularization during training**.

First off (and as a rule of thumb you should always do this) add regularization on the size of the weights by adding to following argument to each of the layers:

```
kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(w_reg)
```

So each of your layers should look like this:

```
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
                    kernel_size=2,
                    activation='tanh',
                    padding="same",
                    kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(w_reg))
```

**Additional observations:**

I think that your model is **too wide for the size of your input**, so it is very easy for it to memorize the training data and overfit. You are using dense layers with 8096 neurons for an input of 192 variables and a single output. In my opinion this is an **overkill** and you should decrease the size to several hundreds of neurons the most. If I am wrong, you will see that your training accuracy doesn't reach the higher 90's and you can always add back neurons.

I noticed that you are using **batch normalization on the input**. In standard cases it is not done. You should normalize your input, but usually it is performed outside of the model by subtracting the mean of the training set and then dividing it by the variance of the training set from each sample (yes, all samples including those of the test set and any future samples are normalized with the mean and variance of the training set).

I also noticed that you are using 2 different activation functions in the model (not including the sigmoid on the output), was it done on purpose or might it be mistake?

Comment: Thank you for reply. About different activation functions, firstly it was relu, but I found out that tanh faster achieves higher accuracy. But final layer should have relu. Am I wrong?

Comment: about normalization, some input arrays may include exceptional too high or too low values due to hardware malfunction. using normalization I try to eliminate their effects

Comment: how to estimate w_reg?

Comment: I added regularization with w_reg=0.01, and reduced number of neurons to 512. Now accuracy stops at 0.6169 from 2nd to 200 epoch. When regularisation is removed from the dense layers, accuracy improves, but slow.

Comment: First comment: The final layer should not have ReLu, In your case the output needs to be a single number between 0 and 1, which can then be rounded to the closest value to get the classification. So sigmoid is the right activation function for your model. (This also the case in your script, the ReLU is in the before last layer, you got sigmoid in your last layer of dense(1))

Comment: Second comment: I think this is wrong. This actually gives more weight to the errors because their high value is distributed among the values of the batch. Your model should see this bad measurements and learn to ignore them.

Comment: Estimating w_reg: I have no way of knowing because it is very task, dataset and model specific. So you will have to do some grid search of different values to see what is working best. Try 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, etc..

Comment: It might mean that the regularization value you are using is too big.

Comment: About batch normalization again... From each of six channels data differs significantly. It can vary from around 700 in one channel in one frame to several thousands in the same channel in another frame. I try to eliminate this effect using batch normalisation. Or in my case it is better to normalize every ray data in each frame separately? The only relevance for classification is presence of local maximums, which form diagonal "rays" across 6 rows.